# Increase any position fixed

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

How can I use javascript to increase every single position:fixed in a page by a number of pixels?

For example:  I have a webpage with several fixed position elements and I insert a toolbar at the top using javascript.  Now that the toolbar takes up 40px of space, all the fixed elements are positioned 40px off.

I need some javascript that I can fire at the same time as introducing the toolbar that will increase all the position fixed by 40px.

Comment: You'll need to give some idea of the relevant mark-up you're using, do the elements requiring repositioning share a class-name?

Comment: Do the fixed elements have a common class?

Comment: Thanks.  The elements could be anything, is it possible to just increase ALL the positions by 40px?

Comment: How many fixed-positioned elements do you have? Please show us some markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a common class to each fixed element and then target all of those:

```
<div class="fixed">
    some fixed element
</div>
```

js (jquery method):

```
$('.fixed').each(function(){
    $(this).css('top', $(this).css('top') + 40 + 'px'); 
});
```

if not using jquery see aurel's answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set the top or the bottom CSS properties of your elements by modifying the style attributes in JS.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine you'd have to do something like this:

```
var elems = document.all || document.getElementsByTagName("*");
// I know document.all isn't ideal, but it saves a function call if it's there ;)
var l = elems.length, i, stl;
window.getComputedStyle = window.getComputedStyle || function(e) {return e.currentStyle};
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
  stl = window.getComputedStyle(elems[i]);
  if( stl.position === "fixed") {
    elems[i].style.marginTop = ((parseInt(stl.marginTop,10) || 0) + 40) + "px";
  }
}
```

The use of `margin-top` as opposed to `top` is to allow for things like `top:50%`. Of course, `margin-top` can be a percentage too, which would be a problem, but it's less frequent.

Comment: Another thing to beware of: elements that are anchored by the `bottom` property should be avoided.

Comment: @Kolink: Why that? It seems necessary for some layouts to me.